# Connect REST API without HTTPS url from Nextron Desktop Application

Tags: rest-api

I'm building a
desktop application using this package "https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nextron"
Which is essentially electron + next.js

In development mode, it is using localhost. From salesforce connected app, I just need to register the localhost url to the whitelist and it works right away.

Unfortunately, in production mode the app using url like this "app://./index.html". This broke things and my app can no longer connect salesforce REST API since it needs url with HTTPS only and I cannot register that url to the whitelist.

Is there any alternative to let a desktop app without https url still able to connect to salesforce REST API ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This very much sounds like a `Nextron` library question as to how do they propose you connect to remote APIs (any remote APIs for that matter, e.g. `https://google.com`)

Comment: @zaitsman you might be right. They provide several ways. But the point here is, the Nextron can do normal api rest call to other api server. Unfortunately, in salesforce rest api, we need to whitelist our rest caller and it is expected the origins must use the HTTPS protocol. The Nextron dekstop app did not use HTTPS protocol. That is my obstacle right now.